# Using the gralloc method Capture screen from Tegra 2 GPU

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, tegra

The Tegra 2/3 SOC does not provide access to framebuffer using the usual /dev/graphics/fb0 dev.
It seems that it's still possible to capture the framebuffer using the gralloc method and actually some applications already use this method.

It seems that there was a patch from Nvidia to allow reading from gralloc.
The source can be found here. it is quite old and there were many changes to android by now.

Does any recent version of android provide any way to read the gralloc buffer?